# Angular 2 Routing 404 on refresh on server

Tags: javascript, angular, apache, angular-routing

When I running my angular 2 project on localhost, I am able to goto a page like so: localhost:4200/register

I then uploaded my project to an apache server and now my routes are not working, I am able to goto the index.html page which brings me to my homepage and I am able to navigate thru my site [routerLink]="['/register']" but when I directly goto the link example.com/register I get a 404 error, but when I goto example.com and click on [routerLink]="['/register']" it takes me to example.com/register....why am I getting a 404 error when I try to goto the page directly?

Here is my app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from '../pages/home/home.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/index';

import { LoginComponent } from '../pages/login/login.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from '../pages/login/logout.component';

import { ProfileHeaderComponent } from '../shared/user/profile-header/profile-header.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from '../pages/profile/profile.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from '../pages/register/register.component';
import { ForgotComponent } from '../pages/forgot/forgot.component';
import { UserComponent } from '../pages/user/user.component';
import { ListComponent } from '../pages/list/list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'account',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'forgot',
    component: ForgotComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'user/:username',
    component: UserComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'search/:type',
    component: ListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'logout',
    component: LogoutComponent
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that all Angular2 routes should be served via the index.html file.

This can be achieved by adding a .htaccess file (in the same directory where the index.html resides) with the following contents.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

For More:https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11884

Check this also:https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Deploying-prod-build-to-Apache-2

Comment: Hai! Glad to Help!!